# configure ssh to allow login with ssh key (and no google 2FA) or password + google 2FA?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, 2-factor-authentication

I'd like to configure my (debian) machine to allow ssh logins with two different options for authentication:

1. ssh public key authentication
2. password authentication with a (google) 2 factor authentication code

The best I've been able to do resulted in the 2FA code being required even when I was using an ssh key.  But that is a deal breaker.

Comment: How is the Google 2FA implemented? .. If you are using a [PAM module](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-libpam) you'll need to adjust PAM settings.

Comment: Yes, I was using Google 2FA via a PAM module.  I'll look into PAM settings.

Comment: You may also be able to do it this way ... Add this to your server's `sshd_config` .... `AuthenticationMethods publickey keyboard-interactive`